# Implementation of new with argument in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I basically want to implement `new` which can accept argument e.x `obj := SomeClass new: 'a'`. I tried to implement this way

```
initialize: bdata
    data := bdata
```

But this doesn't work. seems like I am doing some silly mistake because of lack of knowledge. I try to google it but couldn't find any example. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Smalltalk, `new` and `new:` are not keywords, but regular messages. They are simply implemented by the object's class. To write a method for an objects's class (rather than for an instance), click the "class" button in the system browser. There, you could implement your `new:` method.

Note, however, that it is usually not a good idea to name your own instance creation method `new:`. Since this is a regular method, you can name it anything you want. For example, `MyClass withBData: foo`. Make it a nice descriptive name. It could look like

```
withBData: bdata
    | inst |
    inst := self new.
    inst bdata: bdata.
    ^inst
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is too short to tell what is wrong. In general you should have an initialize with arg, something like this:

```
initialize: arg
  self initialize.
  instVar := arg
```

Then you can implement `new:` like this:

```
new: arg
  ^ self basicNew
     initialize: arg;
     yourself
```

Note that `new` is implemented as `self basicNew initialize`, so if you are calling `initialize` from your custom initialization method, you shouldn't use `new` in your custom new, use `basicNew` instead

Comment: And beginners often overlook that `new:` is a class method, whereas `initialize:` is an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basicNew method if you need to use your argument in the initialize method (as Uko mentions in his answer above).

```
withBData: bdata
    ^ (self basicNew bdata: bdata) initialize
```